# JQueryMobile 1.4.2 + Android 2.2/2.3 forms

Tags: javascript, android, css, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm working in a phonegap project with JQueryMobile 1.4.2 and I have a problem with old android devices. It works in android modern versions but, forms have issues over 2.2 and 2.3 versions.

On Android 2.2 devices: I can't use inputs because when I click screen (anywhere) button is pressed.

On Android 2.3 devices: When I start to write on input text field, screen starts to scroll up and down.

Any idea?
Head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.css" />   
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js"></script>
```

Form:

```
<form id="form_login" method="post" name="form_login" onsubmit="login();">
    <div id="modulo_login">
        <div data-i18n="acces.subtit" id="tit_mlu"></div><input id="nif_nie"
        name="nif_nie" tabindex="1" type="text" /> <input id="pwd" name="pwd"
        tabindex="2" type="password" />

        <div id="pwd_mlu">
            <a data-i18n="acces_particular.olv" data-transition="slide" href=
            "rec_contr.html"></a>
        </div>
    </div><input class="btn" data-i18n="[value]acces.entrar" tabindex="3" type=
    "submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: pretty sure the webview in those SDKs doesn't support data attributes.

Comment: thanks but data-i18n works, the problems are with JQueryMobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the issue you explained with android 2.3 devices and solved it removing from all css files the following property: -webkit-backface-visibility.